# Model for the change of quantity over time everyday

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I am finding a model for the change of DNS request between any 2 continuous periods every day. This is used to optimize the work of our data center.

Let me take an example here.

- On the first day of January, from 1 am to 2 am (first period), we capture 1000 DNS request. And from 2 am to 3 am (second period), we capture 2000 DNS request.
- On the second day of January, from 1 am to 2 am, we capture 1400 DNS request. And from 2 am to 3 am, we capture 3000 DNS request.

And so on, so we could capture data like above in a month.

As we could see from here, on the first day, the number of captured DNS request increases by 100% in the second period comparing to the first period, and on the second day, it increases by more than 100%.

So my question is, is there any possible model for the changing rate of the number of DNS request like above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than model/predict a percent change over ... actually predict the value by hour and by day. I would summarize the data by day and build a model that might include memory (ARIMA) and deterministic factors like day-of-the-week, day-of-the-month, week-of-the-month, month-of-the year and holiday effects et al. I would then build 24 hourly models and use daily totals as a possible predictor. Both types of models ( the daily and the hourly ) may have level shifts , local time trends and anomalous effects and would need to be identified and utilized. Finally you can always convert your forecasts to rates if you wish.

This is precisely what was done here http://demand-planning.com/2010/03/18/can-forecasting-help-me-staff-a-specific-hewlett-packard-call-center-at-1030-am-on-a-friday/

Comment: Thank you, sir. I think your answer reveals what I need to read and research more now. ARIMA model could be a good model for me to try.

Comment: BUT ARIMA alone will not suffice as there probably will be deterministic effects present waiting to be discovered.